# Unity - Null Reference when instantiating new object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to cycle through a 2D array of card objects and instantiate them in my Unity scene.  However, I'm getting a Null reference exception when trying to instantiate them.  Here is the code that instantiates the objects:

```
//Setting up initial board
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            //Checked with debug.log, this should work Debug.Log (board[j, i].name);
            Debug.Log(board[j, i].name);
            temp = Instantiate(board[j,i]) as GameObject;
            CardScript cs = temp.GetComponent<CardScript>();
            objectBoard[j, i] = cs;
            //Setting locations of the cards
            objectBoard[j, i].transform.position = new Vector3(30 * j + 20, 50 * i +   70, 0);
        }
    }
```

The error occurs in the line 'CardScript cs = new....  I originally had the error in the temp = Instantiate... line, when the code was GameObject temp = Instantiate.... It fixed when I made temp a private GameObject variable in the code.  I don't think I can do that with this one, because I need to have a reference to each individual object I'm instantiating.

Full Code:

```
public class MatchScript : MonoBehaviour {

public CardScript[] potentialCards;

private CardScript[,] board;
private CardScript[,] objectBoard;
private List<CardScript> entries;
private GameObject temp;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    entries = new List<CardScript> ();
    objectBoard = new CardScript[4,3];
    board = new CardScript[4, 3];
    foreach (CardScript c in potentialCards)
        entries.Add (c);
    foreach (CardScript c in potentialCards)
        entries.Add (c);

    //Loading up the board
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            int k = Random.Range(0, entries.Count);
            board[j, i] = entries[k];

            entries.RemoveAt(k);
        }
    }

    //Setting up initial board
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            //Checked with debug.log, this should work Debug.Log (board[j, i].name);
            Debug.Log(board[j, i].name);
            temp = Instantiate(board[j,i]) as GameObject;
            CardScript cs = temp.GetComponent<CardScript>();
            objectBoard[j, i] = cs;
            //Setting locations of the cards
            objectBoard[j, i].transform.position = new Vector3(30 * j + 20, 50 * i + 70, 0);
        }
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

Comment: The C# `as` operator is a run time safe cast - if the type cannot be cast to the destination type, rather than throw an `InvalidCastException`, the operator returns `null`. You haven't shown the code for `Instantiate(board[j,i])`, which is the method's result that you're casting to `GameObject`. If the result of that method is not an instance of  `GameObject`, `cs` will be set to `null`, and your next line will *always* throw a null reference exception when you attempt to invoke `GetComponent<CardScript>()` on a null reference.

Comment: Sorry, Unity has a built in function for Instantiate, I didn't write it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why this happen. But you can fix this by change

```
temp = Instantiate(board[j,i]) as GameObject;
```

to

```
temp = Instantiate(board[j,i].gameObject) as GameObject;
```

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing to make it work.  You can't pass in a child of a Gameobject to Instantiate without it returning null.  I just changed the unity variable that came in to a GameObject, passed in the same CardScript, and pulled out the CardScript piece after instantiating it.

Answer (score 1):

"expression **as** Type" clause returns expression cast to Type if and only if actual type of expression is derived from Type, otherwise it returns null.

[Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) makes an independent copy of an object passed, which, naturally, has type CardScript. Now, there is some possible misunderstanding: GameObject is a base class for all "entities in Unity scenes", but that doesn't include all classes you create on your own. If CardScript is a class you created and it doesn't inherit any class explicitly, then it inherits System.Object (which is base class for *all* C# classes).

If CardScript is derived from GameObject, then you should probably provide that class as well.